# Configuration steps to Allow Backorders AND Filter for In Stock/Out of Stock Items

Tags: out-of-stock, stock-status, backorder

This looks like it has similar questions asked about it, but nothing recent, and I cant believe a platform the size of magento can't handle this - unless I'm missing something obvious in my site configuration.

We are a B2B website, we have about 4000 products, some regularly stocked, some special ordered. Every single product should be able to be ordered whether it is normally stocked or not, and whether it has a current stock value above zero or not - ie Backorders should be allowed.

However, I would also like our customers to be able to select the In Stock/out of Stock filter in Layered navigation so that if they have a more urgent order they can reduce the category page down to only show items with a positive stock value.

This seems to be where magento fails - I can have Backorders turned on and then any product can be ordered regardless of stock value, however to do this I have to make every single product as "In Stock", and therefore the navigation filter on the front end does not work as magento shows every product to be in stock. If I manually set the product as Out of Stock then I cant "Add to Cart" on the front end

The entire principal of a backorder is to allow an out of stock item to be (back) ordered, so how is it magento requires those items to be classed as in stock??

hopefully someone has worked out how to make this possible??

we've tried setting out of stock threshold to -1, and -10000, various lines of code found on several blog posts, etc - but most are years old posts, and none seem to fix the problem

We generally create new SKUs with an opening stock value of zero as new products typically aren't yet in stock in the warehouse - maybe I need to create each new SKU with a stock value of 1 and In Stock and then let the value drop to zero by placing an order - will this trick the system to consider it as out of stock for the layered nav but not make it out of stock from an ordering perspective and block backorders?

thanks in advance for any help